# Checkbox input array values passed to insert into MySQL query based on selections

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

My array of checkbox inputs is displaying and working perfect:

```
<input name="seminar[<?php echo $a; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="seminar_<?php echo $a; ?> "value="" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
```

This is my MySQL insert data ($s):

```
if ($seminar) { 
    foreach ($seminar as $s )
        $interest .= "$s ";
}
```

My earlier `for` loop that processes the checkbox inputs above, does not store the data in `$s`. And I am trying to find a way to store those values to pass to that `foreach`.

Comment: I tried ...foreach ($seminar[$a]... but obviously that does not work because my earlier loop is confined to the generation of the checkboxes.

Comment: Please reformat code, because right now it looks like your checkboxes have empty value. Of course this explains why you will not get anything in `$interest` string except for spaces, but I don't think that the problem is so trivial :)

Comment: I am working with someone elses code, and its seems like it's just a mess of junk! This was done so wrong I am finding out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="3">
```

your checkbox is something like this...............ok.

then in php you just post the variable

```
<?php $apple=$_POST['apple'];
   ?>
```

now the $apple is an array of your selected values.
is it ok for your project.....................

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insight.